# Prevent UserControl from rendering each time it is used

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-controls

I am developing plain WPF application on top of .NET 5.0.
I have navigation mechanism implemented based on DataTemplate(s)

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:FirstViewModel}">
            <views:FirstView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:SecondViewModel}">
            <views:SecondView />
        </DataTemplate>
```

and CurrentViewModel

```
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

You can imagine there are navbar buttons changing the CurrentViewModel property.
Besides that I use Dependency Injection which provides all required services (including viewmodels).
Both **FirstViewModel** and **SecondViewModel** are singletons.
**FirstView** and **SecondView** are UserControl(s).

**The problem:**
Whenever I navigate between UserControls they re-render. This is very inconvinient, from performance perspective and application usability.
Let's say both UserControls have grids with searching features and more. I would like user to be able to navigate back to the same state which he left on the control (including focused elements and so on). Having singleton viewmodel allows to preserve state/values of the properties but it doesn't solve the problem of control being re-rendered whenever I navigate. I clearly see that each time FirstView constructor is being called on which it **InitializeComponent()** and later calls **OnRender()**.
Grids have asynchronous **Sources**.

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveSearchResults, IsAsync=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False">
.
.
.
</DataGrid>
```

I don't want grid to be re-rendered each time I navigate and elements to lose their focus. When I navigate I also see the grid flikering.

Can you please suggest option I have?
Is it possible to have singleton UserControl?
Is it possible to have static property with a cached state?

Comment: Have you looked Prism, you can keep the views alive during navigation: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Introduction.html

Comment: We don't want to use any frameworks. We just used MvvmCross which introduced a lot of limitations.

Comment: Re-assigning the Content property of a ContentControl will inevitably re-create the elements in the DataTemplate associated with the Content type. You may perhaps have two ContentControls, assign each Content once, and only change their Visibilty.

Comment: @Clemens I guess that is an idea worth giving a try. Thanks!

Comment: Changing Visibility to Hidden will not unload your control, while to Collapsed will.